# observing attributes on Ember.computer.alias never firing

Tags: ember.js

I am observing searchModel but searchInvalid is never firing.  Why is this?  Also, is there a way i can observe all searchModel attributes instead of having to list them all?

```
export default Ember.ArrayController.extend(InfiniteScroll.ControllerMixin, {
    needs : ['search'],
    searchModel: Ember.computed.alias("controllers.search.model"),

    searchInvalid : function() {
        this.transitionToRoute('search');
    }.observes( 'searchModel.sortColumn', 'searchModel.sortDirection', 'searchModel.loadNumber',
                'searchModel.vehicleRegistration', 'searchModel.driverName', 'searchModel.site',
                'searchModel.fromPlanDate','searchModel.toPlanDate'), //is there a way to watch the entire model?

    perPage: 25,
    page : 1

});
```

UPDATE

---

I just got this working by using the following syntax instead:

```
searchModelBinding: "controllers.search.model",
```

1. Why does this work but the above doesn't?
2. And I am still unclear on how to observer all attributes on a model

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ember won't observe a property that's never been fetched.  It's kind of weird, but it's a lazy loading concept that's a little wonky.

```
export default Ember.ArrayController.extend(InfiniteScroll.ControllerMixin, {
    foo: function(){
      this.get('searchModel'); // prime the engines.
    }.on('init'), 
    needs : ['search'],
    searchModel: Ember.computed.alias("controllers.search.model"),

    searchInvalid : function() {
        this.transitionToRoute('search');
    }.observes( 'searchModel.sortColumn', 'searchModel.sortDirection', 'searchModel.loadNumber',
                'searchModel.vehicleRegistration', 'searchModel.driverName', 'searchModel.site',
                'searchModel.fromPlanDate','searchModel.toPlanDate'), //is there a way to watch the entire model?

    perPage: 25,
    page : 1

});
```

And no, there isn't any way of watching every item on the model.